# Serving Images With Express Framework

Tags: linux, node.js, express, digital-ocean

I am trying to serve .png using the express framework, but keep receiving a "Cannot /get" error.

```
var express  = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    app  = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/public/media', express.static(__dirname + '/public/media/img0.png'));
app.listen(port);

console.log(__dirname + '/public/media/img0.png');
```

I print out the directory name of my file to ensure I have the right path. Delving deeper into the develepor tools however shows the resource could not be loaded due to 404 error.

My file structure is something like this.

```
   -- admin
     -- app.js public
       -- media
         -- img0.png img1.png
```

From what I have seen, my static file server should work, so I am at a bit of a loss. Thoughts?

Comment: What URL are you accessing? http://localhost:3000/public/media or http://localhost:3000/public/media/img0.png or something else?

Comment: I am using my digitaloceanip:3000. From there, I tried walking down my file path to see if it would return anything, but I kept receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this line:

```
app.use('/public/media', express.static(__dirname + '/public/media/img0.png'));
```

That says that if the browser asks for `/public/media`, then please serve up the PNG file. So that will work.

If the browser asks for `/public/media/img0.png`, then that will be a 404.

It seems likely that you meant this instead:

```
app.use('/public/media', express.static(__dirname + '/public/media'));
```

That will serve a 404 for `/public/media` but will serve any image you specify in that directory if the corresponding image file exists. So if the browser asks for `/public/media/img0.png`, it will get it.

Comment: That would do it. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You might try applying `static` to the whole directory:

```
app.use('/public/media', express.static(__dirname + '/public/media/'));
```

Comment: I am a little confused at what you mean. Are you saying add this additional statement to me existing code? If so, what is the difference between applying it to the resource like I did, and what you are saying?

Comment: The way you've configured it, you'd have to route `/public/media/img01.png` not `/public/media`. You've mapped a directory to a file, so it's not consistent.